# LINQ analogues in Scala?

Tags: linq, scala

Are there any sane analogues to LINQ (.NET) exists for Scala?

Comment: Specific LINQ method matched to the scala equivalent : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104846/chart-of-ienumerable-linq-equivalents-in-scala

Comment: LINQ for Scala (full API) & deferred execution support: https://github.com/nicholas22/propelS

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8106548/192247. Might be useful.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you mean by "LINQ". LINQ is many things.

The most obvious answer would be: just use the .NET port of Scala. It gives you full native access to everything in .NET, which obviously includes LINQ.

Unfortunately, the .NET port of Scala was dropped a couple of years ago. Fortunately, it was picked up again a couple of months ago, with official funding directly from Microsoft no less. You can expect a release sometime in the 2011/2012 timeframe.

Anyway, what is LINQ?

A couple of features where added to .NET and specifically C# and VB.NET *for* LINQ. They are not technically part of LINQ, but are necessary prerequisites: type inference, anonymous (structural) types, lambda expressions, function types (`Func<T...>` and `Action<T...>`) and expression trees. All of these have been in Scala for a long time, most have been there forever.

Also not directly part of LINQ, but in C#, LINQ query expressions can be used to generate XML, to emulate VB.NET's XML literals. Scala has XML literals, like VB.NET.

More specifically, LINQ is

- a specification for a set of standard query operators
- a set of implementations for those operators (i.e. `IQueryable`, LINQ-to-XML, LINQ-to-SQL, LINQ-to-Objects)
- a built-in embedded syntax for LINQ query comprehensions
- a monad

In Scala, like in pretty much any other functional language (and in fact also pretty much any other object-oriented language, too), the query operators are simply part of the standard collections API. In .NET, they have a little bit weird names, whereas in Scala, they have the same standard names they have in other languages: `Select` is `map`, `Aggregate` is `reduce` (or `fold`), `SelectMany` is `flatMap`, `Where` is `filter` or `withFilter`, `orderBy` is `sort` or `sortBy` or `sortWith`, and there are `zip`, `take` and `takeWhile` and so on. So, that takes care of both the specification and the LINQ-to-Objects implementation. Scala's XML libraries also implement the collections APIs, which takes care of LINQ-to-XML.

SQL APIs are not built into Scala, but there are third-party APIs which implement the collection API.

Scala also has specialized syntax for those APIs, but unlike Haskell, which tries to make them look like imperative C blocks and C#, which tries to make them look like SQL queries, Scala tries to make them look like `for` loops. They are called *`for` comprehensions* and are the equivalent to C#'s query comprehensions and Haskell's monad comprehensions. (They also replace C#'s `foreach` and generators (`yield return`)).

But if you *really* want to know whether or not there are analogues for LINQ in Scala, you will first have to specificy what exactly you mean by "LINQ". (And of course, if you want to know whether they are "sane", you will have to define that, too.)

Comment: The most useful part of the answer is "Select is map, Where is filter or withFilter, orderBy is sort or sortBy or sortWith,...". I am just missing Count(), First(), FirstOrDefault().

Comment: `size`, `head`, `headOption.getOrElse`.These are all in [scala.collection.Iterable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html)

Comment: One *huge* advantage LINQ has is that it supports deconstruction into Expression Trees which allows all the LINQ2SQL magic to "just work". Syntax aside, this level of expression tree integration is not currently available in Scala so all the "corresponding providers" must effectively also provide their own AST handling without this level of abstraction.

Comment: @pst: yeah, you could currently probably do this with a VCR type `Dynamic` object that captures all method calls, but that's pretty brittle and a fair bit of complexity. Let's see what virtualized Scala and Macros bring to the table.

Comment: any ideas what happened to .NET port of Scala? was it discontinued?

Comment: @chester89: Neither EPFL nor TypeSafe have anyone assigned to it, and the .NET backend will be removed from the Scala 2.11 distribution.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, that's sad. I'd be happy to help, but I guess my skills (especially in Scala) are not enough for a project of that magnitude  :(

Comment: What the OP meant by LINQ is clear and obvious.  Would have been a great answer without being anal about the definition of LINQ.  I mean really , who cares?

Answer (score 39):

All LINQ `IEnumerable` extensions are available in Scala. For example:

Linq:

```
var total = orders
       .Where(o => o.Customer == "myCustomer")
       .SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems)
       .Aggregate(0, (sum, current) => sum + current.Price * current.Count);
```

scala:

```
val total = orders
       .filter(o => o.customer == "myCustomer")
       .flatMap(o => o.orderItems)
       .foldLeft(0)((s, c) => s + c.price * c.count)
```

Comment: @oleksii forAll and exists. http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html

Answer (score 10):

**Slick**

is a modern database query and access library for Scala. 
(http://slick.typesafe.com/)

```
@table("COFFEES") case class Coffee(
  @column("COF_NAME")  name:  String,
  @column("SUP_ID") supID: Int,
  @column("PRICE") price: Double
)
val coffees = Queryable[Coffee]


// for inserts use lifted embedding or SQL
val l = for {
  c <- coffees if c.supID == 101
  //                       ^ comparing Int to Int!
} yield (c.name, c.price)


backend.result( l, session )
 .foreach { case (n, p) => println(n + ": " + p) }
```

Answer (score 8):

There are many situations in Scala where you can use monadic constructs as a sort of query language.

For example, to query XML (in this case, extracting URLs from links in some XHTML):

```
def findURLs(xml: NodeSeq): Seq[URL] = 
  for {
    a <- xml \\ "a"
    href <- a attribute "href"
    url <- href.text
  } yield URL(url)
```

For an analogue of LINQ to SQL, the closest thing is probably [ScalaQuery](http://github.com/szeiger/scala-query/wiki). To lift an example right out of the docs:

```
val q4c = for {
  u <- Users
  o <- Orders if o.userID is u.id
} yield u.first ~ o.orderID
```