# Chart of IEnumerable LINQ equivalents in Scala?

Tags: c#, linq, scala, ienumerable, iterable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ analogues in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785413/linq-analogues-in-scala)

I am looking for chart which shows equivalents in Scala of LINQ methods for IEnumerable:

- First is head
- Select is map
- SingleOrDefault is ... (I don't know)
- ... and so on

Does anyone know anything of such "translate" table?

Comment: Why settle for anything less than LINQ for Scala (full API re-implementation): https://github.com/nicholas22/propelS

Comment: @casperOne: Why not merge the two threads?

Comment: This question is nowhere near being a duplicate of the other one. This question is much more focused and concrete, whereas the other one is vaguer. Both are valid and different.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate assessment. This is quite different and more helpful.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I am only listing out the equivalents of functions from `Enumerable<A>`. This is incomplete as of now. I will try to update this later with more.

```
xs.Aggregate(accumFunc)              -> xs.reduceLeft(accumFunc)
xs.Aggregate(seed, accumFunc)        -> xs.foldLeft(seed)(accumFunc)
xs.Aggregate(seed, accumFunc, trans) -> trans(xs.foldLeft(seed)(accumFunc))
xs.All(pred)                         -> xs.forall(pred)
xs.Any()                             -> xs.nonEmpty
xs.Any(pred)                         -> xs.exists(pred)
xs.AsEnumerable()                    -> xs.asTraversable // roughly
xs.Average()                         -> xs.sum / xs.length
xs.Average(trans)                    -> trans(xs.sum / xs.length)
xs.Cast<A>()                         -> xs.map(_.asInstanceOf[A])
xs.Concat(ys)                        -> xs ++ ys
xs.Contains(x)                       -> xs.contains(x) //////
xs.Contains(x, eq)                   -> xs.exists(eq(x, _))
xs.Count()                           -> xs.size
xs.Count(pred)                       -> xs.count(pred)
xs.DefaultIfEmpty()                  -> if(xs.isEmpty) List(0) else xs // Use `mzero` (from Scalaz) instead of 0 for more genericity
xs.DefaultIfEmpty(v)                 -> if(xs.isEmpty) List(v) else xs
xs.Distinct()                        -> xs.distinct
xs.ElementAt(i)                      -> xs(i)
xs.ElementAtOrDefault(i)             -> xs.lift(i).orZero // `orZero` is from Scalaz
xs.Except(ys)                        -> xs.diff(ys)
xs.First()                           -> xs.head
xs.First(pred)                       -> xs.find(pred) // returns an `Option`
xs.FirstOrDefault()                  -> xs.headOption.orZero
xs.FirstOrDefault(pred)              -> xs.find(pred).orZero
xs.GroupBy(f)                        -> xs.groupBy(f)
xs.GroupBy(f, g)                     -> xs.groupBy(f).mapValues(_.map(g))
xs.Intersect(ys)                     -> xs.intersect(ys)
xs.Last()                            -> xs.last
xs.Last(pred)                        -> xs.reverseIterator.find(pred) // returns an `Option`
xs.LastOrDefault()                   -> xs.lastOption.orZero
xs.LastOrDefault(pred)               -> xs.reverseIterator.find(pred).orZero
xs.Max()                             -> xs.max
xs.Max(f)                            -> xs.maxBy(f)
xs.Min()                             -> xs.min
xs.Min(f)                            -> xs.minBy(f)
xs.OfType<A>()                       -> xs.collect { case x: A => x }
xs.OrderBy(f)                        -> xs.sortBy(f)
xs.OrderBy(f, comp)                  -> xs.sortBy(f)(comp) // `comp` is an `Ordering`.
xs.OrderByDescending(f)              -> xs.sortBy(f)(implicitly[Ordering[A]].reverse)
xs.OrderByDescending(f, comp)        -> xs.sortBy(f)(comp.reverse)
Enumerable.Range(start, count)       -> start until start + count
Enumerable.Repeat(x, times)          -> Iterator.continually(x).take(times)
xs.Reverse()                         -> xs.reverse
xs.Select(trans)                     -> xs.map(trans) // For indexed overload, first `zipWithIndex` and then `map`.
xs.SelectMany(trans)                 -> xs.flatMap(trans)
xs.SequenceEqual(ys)                 -> xs.sameElements(ys)
xs.Skip(n)                           -> xs.drop(n)
xs.SkipWhile(pred)                   -> xs.dropWhile(pred)
xs.Sum()                             -> xs.sum
xs.Sum(f)                            -> xs.map(f).sum // or `xs.foldMap(f)`. Requires Scalaz.
xs.Take(n)                           -> xs.take(n)
xs.TakeWhile(pred)                   -> xs.takeWhile(pred)
xs.OrderBy(f).ThenBy(g)              -> xs.sortBy(x => (f(x), g(x))) // Or: xs.sortBy(f &&& g). `&&&` is from Scalaz.
xs.ToArray()                         -> xs.toArray // Use `xs.toIndexedSeq` for immutable indexed sequence.
xs.ToDictionary(f)                   -> xs.map(f.first).toMap // `first` is from Scalaz. When f = identity, you can just write `xs.toMap`.
xs.ToList()                          -> xs.toList // This returns an immutable list. Use `xs.toBuffer` if you want a mutable list.
xs.Union(ys)                         -> xs.union(ys)
xs.Where(pred)                       -> xs.filter(pred)
xs.Zip(ys, f)                        -> (xs, ys).zipped.map(f) // When f = identity, use `xs.zip(ys)`
```

---

There is no direct equivalent of some functions, but it's fairly easy to roll your own. Here are some such functions.

**Single**:

```
def single[A](xs: Traversable[A]): A = {
  if(xs.isEmpty) sys error "Empty sequence!"
  else if(xs.size > 1) sys error "More than one elements!"
  else xs.head
}
```

**SingleOrDefault**:

```
def singleOrDefault[A : Zero](xs: Traversable[A]): A = {
  if(xs.isEmpty) mzero
  else if(xs.size > 1) sys error "More than one elements!"
  else xs.head
}
```

**Join**:

```
def join[A, B, K, R](outer: Traversable[A], inner: Traversable[B])
    (outKey: A => K, inKey: B => K, f: (A, B) => R): Traversable[R] = {
  for(o <- outer; i <- inner; if outKey(o) == inKey(i)) yield f(o, i)
}
```

**GroupJoin**:

```
def groupJoin[A, B, K, R](outer: Traversable[A], inner: Traversable[B])
    (outKey: A => K, inKey: B => K, f: (A, Traversable[B]) => R): Traversable[R] = {
  for(o <- outer) yield {
    val zs = for(i <- inner; if outKey(o) == inKey(i)) yield i
    f(o, zs)
  }
}
```

---

**Notes**:

1. In idiomatic Scala, total functions are generally preferred over partial functions. So, idiomatic implementation of `single` and `singleOrDefault` would produce a value of type `Either[Exception, A]` instead of `A`. For example, here is refined implementation of `single` that returns `Either[Exception, A]`.

   ```
   def single[A](xs: Traversable[A]): Either[Exception, A] = {
     if(xs.isEmpty) Left(new RuntimeException("Empty sequence!"))
     else if(xs.size > 1) Left(new RuntimeException("More than one elements!"))
     else Right(xs.head)
   }
   ```
2. Scalaz's `Zero`/`mzero` are not quite same as C#'s `default` value mechanism. For details, you can refer to [this](http://missingfaktor.blogspot.com/2011/08/emulating-cs-default-keyword-in-scala.html) post I wrote on this topic some time back.
3. You can use enrich-my-library pattern to achieve the same effect as C#'s extension methods. Refer to [this](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410846/how-do-i-apply-the-pimp-my-library-pattern-to-scala-collections) for details.

Comment: Thank you VERY much!!! When updating, if there is no 1:1 mapping, please just put it as "no 1:1" mapping, thank you in advance.

Comment: The third `Aggregate` is incorrect. `trans(xs.foldLeft(seed)(accumFunc))` is proper.

Comment: @missingfaktor: Would it be possible to use that list for docs.scala-lang.org?

Comment: `start to start + count - 1` => `start until start + count`

Comment: @soc: That's a great idea. There are a few functions (`Single*`, `GroupJoin`, `Join` etc.) which are still to be covered. Once that's done, you can use this for docs.scala-lang.org.

Comment: @soc: Looks much better with `until`. Updated, thanks!

Comment: @macias: What do you mean by that? Almost none of this is a 1:1 equivalent.

Comment: @missingfaktor, I consider a translation which rather requires something more substantial than 1-liner as not as 1:1 mapping.

Comment: @soc: I updated my answer. You can now use it for docs.scala-lang.org. :-)

Comment: @macias: Check the updated answer. The functions with no 1:1 mapping (as per your definition) are described separately.

Comment: @missingfaktor, how can I upvote you by +100? ;-) Now, I am new to Scala but I think second checking for size in SingleXX would be faster with coll.tail.isEmpty -- this should be O(1), instead of size's O(n).

Comment: @macias: Oh, indeed. Most of the times I use `Vector` instead of `List`. Hence the oversight. I'll update the codes as per your suggestion.

Comment: @macias: I wrote these codes with general collection interfaces (such as `Traversable`, `Seq`) in mind. The fact that `size` is an `O(n)` operation is specific to lists, and is not necessarily applicable to other types of collections. I am now updating the code accordingly.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. They must a create an ISO standard for collection APIs.

Comment: @DmitryOrnatsky, thanks. :) We don't have to go to those lengths. It will be more than sufficient if Microsoft's APIs conform to the common names and conventions, instead of inventing new ones.

Comment: Your chart is inaccurate for `Average`: `xs.Average(trans)` is wrong, should be `trans(xs).sum / xs.length` for non-nullable types. For `xs.Average()`: average of ints is a double, not an int. As well, in both cases for nullable types nulls are not counted.

Comment: As well, LINQ's `xs.Max(f)` is indeed `f(xs).max`.

Comment: Excellent! I would make an up vote for this answer once a day!

Comment: How about `partition`?: `def partition(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): (List[A], List[A])`

Partitions this traversable collection in two traversable collections according to a predicate

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about C# or LINQ, but is this what you're looking for?

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> l.head
res0: Int = 1

scala> l.headOption
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> l.map(_.toString)
res2: List[java.lang.String] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> l(1)
res3: Int = 2
```

There's no method to get an element or a default, but this will work:

```
scala> scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch.opt(l(5)) getOrElse 0
res4: Int = 0
```

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for complete LINQ -> Scala translation, so I could mentally be on right track faster. Something to print, read and memorize.

Comment: For that last one, you could have done `l.lift(5).getOrElse(0)`.