# Getting the element from a 1-element Scala collection

Tags: scala

Learning Scala and I keep wanting an equivalent to [LINQ's Single() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx). Example,

```
val collection: Seq[SomeType]
val (desiredItem, theOthers) = collection.partition(MyFunc)

desiredItem.single.doSomething
         // ^^^^^^
```

I could use `desiredItem.head` but what if MyFunc actually matched several? I want the assurance that there's only one.

**Edit #2** The duplicate question says 'no there isn't but here's how to build it'. So I am thinking if this was a common need it would be in the base API. Do properly written Scala programs need this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chart of IEnumerable LINQ equivalents in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104846/chart-of-ienumerable-linq-equivalents-in-scala)

Comment: Thanks @Maxim. It says there is no builtin equivalent and roll your own. In which case my question: is it unidiomatic to need such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use something more verbose instead of `single`:

```
 (desiredItem match {
   case Seq(single) => single
   case _ => throw IllegalStateException("Not a single element!")
 }).doSomething
```

Its advantage over `single` is that it allows you to explicitly control the behavior in exceptional case (trow an exception, return fallback value).

Alternatively you can use destructuring assignment:

```
val Seq(single) = desiredItem
single.doSomething
```

In this case you'll get `MatchError` if `desiredItem` doesn't contain exactly one element.

**UPD**: I looked again at your code. Destructuring assignment is the way to go for you:

```
val collection: Seq[SomeType]
val (Seq(desiredItem), theOthers) = collection.partition(MyFunc)

desiredItem.doSomething
```

Comment: @SethTisue, probably "destructuring assignment" is better term. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no prebuilt method in the API to do that. You can create your own method to do something similar though.

```
scala> def single[A](xs: List[A]) = xs match{ 
 | case List() => None
 | case x::Nil => Some(x)
 | case x::xs => throw new Exception("More than one element")
     | }
single: [A](xs: Seq[A])Option[A]

scala> single(List(1,2,3))
java.lang.Exception: More than one element
  at .single(<console>:11)
  ... 33 elided

scala> single(List(1))
res13: Any = Some(1)

scala> single(List())
res14: Any = None
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you usually define this method in your own programs? (I was wondering if it was intentionally left out of base API and I shouldn't need it)

Comment: I personally don't but you could if it comes up enough. I'll guess it was left out of the API because you can build it out of the functions provided. C# provides it in the API as a feature.

Comment: This is buggy; your method accepts all `Seq`s, but only actually works on `List`s.

Answer (score 1):

Like others indicated, there is no library implementation of what you seek. But it's easy to implement your own using a Pimp My Library approach. For example you can do the following.

```
object Main extends App {
    object PML {
      implicit class TraversableOps[T](val collection: TraversableOnce[T]) {
        def single: Option[T] = collection.toList match {
          case List(x) => Some(x)
          case _ => None
        }
      }
    }

    import PML._
    val collection: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2)
    val (desiredItem, theOthers) = collection.partition(_ < 2)
    println(desiredItem.single)  // Some(1)
    println(collection.single)   // None
    println(List.empty.single)   // None
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I ended up with.