# How mature is scala slick?

Tags: linq, scala

I've been looking for some language integrated ways of accessing the database with Scala, and I came across [slick](https://github.com/slick/slick). It seems pretty, uh, slick, but I'm curious as to its maturity. I see that it has a variety of database back-end implementations, which is super-cool, but how soon is the abstraction likely to leak (every database abstraction does)?

To phrase this another way, would you pitch this as a preferred way to do database access to your boss? If so, what would the pitch be, otherwise why not?

Rationale: I think .NET's LINQ is cool, and so is Scala. Can one effectively have both?

Comment: There's a number of Scala DSLs for accessing the databases, both relational and postrelational. In my humble opinion at this moment these frameworks, such as squeryl or slick are there for a reason and not having one 'standard' LINQ is good for competition and development. You might also want to look for more answers on SO like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785413/linq-analogues-in-scala

Comment: Since this question just got closed while I was writing an answer, left me post this here instead. SLICK is the continuation of ScalaQuery which has been around for quite some time (started by me in 2009), so I'd consider most of what you see there pretty mature already. The really new part of SLICK is the macro- and reflection-based front-end which is certainly not mature (neither is the macro implementation in Scala 2.10 - it's still considered experimental).